# Appearance of user id when downloading to the file

Tags: php, pdf, converters, epub

There's this code which I have

```
function pushfile(&$file) {
    header_remove();
  if (isset($file["type"])) header('Content-Type: '.$file["type"]);
  if (isset($file["name"])) header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file["name"].'"');
  print $file["name"];
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Pragma: ");
  echo $file["content"];
  exit;

$h=fopen($filename,"r");
        $content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
        fclose($h);
        $file["type"] = "application/";  //
        $file["name"] = $real_filename;
        $file["content"] = $content."*".$context['user']['id'];
        pushfile($file);
```

This ID number was well placed into the downloaded file, but it disappeared after  converting it (e.g. from pdf to epub). Is there a good solution for that?

Comment: your user id is out of bounds of the internal file format, thats why it gets ommited during conversion, you could write the user id into metadata section and hope converters works with them properly, but converters usually omit these by default, you could edit the pdf and put the user id as part of the document data, both can be removed, even with conversion to image with watermark isn't 100% because of OCR and document re-creation

Comment: and if I put the ID in the middle? Is that possible to do?